# how to tackle such word problems of algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A $140$ feet long wire needs to be cut into two pieces such that one piece will be $\frac{2}{5}$ as long as the other. How many feet the shorter piece will be?

lets the shorter piece size be x

then the other piece size is 2x/5

now,

x + 2x/5 = 140

7x/5 = 140

x = 100

The answer is actually 40.

Comment: $2/5$ longer? Do you mean $2/5$ of a foot longer, or $2/5$ times the length of the other, or $1+2/5$ times the length of the other? Also, show what you've tried so far. It's poor form to submit a question without showing any sign of even trying.

Comment: This is a ratio question in disguise.

Comment: Updated my attempt the question wording correctly.

Comment: Out of $x$ and $2x/5$, which is smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is correct. Only mistake is you have taken longer piece as x not shorter piece . Note that 2/5×X will be smaller than X. So the value 100 is of longer piece

So shorter piece's length will be 140-100=40

Comment: How can I do these things orally/mentally? I cannot imagine

Comment: What things which is shorter and which is longer?

Comment: Rather than algebra x,y how can I solve mentally

Comment: You have to follow same method. The calculation is quite easy to do it mentally.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: This answer was suitable for the question asked originally. Now, the method is informative but the ratios have changed.

Let's call one bit $a$ and one bit $b$.
$$ 140 = a + b $$

Let's relate the two.  $b$ will be given by 
$$ b = \frac{7a}{5} $$

$$140 = a  + \frac{7a}{5}
$$

Make both expressions of a, have the same denominator 
$$140 = \frac{5a}{5}  + \frac{7a}{5}
$$

Add them
$$140 = \frac{12a}{5} 
$$

Re-arrange
$$a = \frac{700}{12} $$

$$b = \frac{7 \times 700}{5 \times 12} $$
$ a= 58.3333 $ recurring

$b = 81.6666666 $ recurring

Comment: Updated the wordings of the question - the answer is actually 40